# Postgres search in JSON

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

My `probe_table` looks like this:

id | my_metadata

The `probe` column is JSON, with the following:

```
{
  "myProbe": {
    "someField": "20",
    "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  }
}
```

I'm trying to search in all `probe` columns a specific IP.

I have tried:

```
SELECT * 
      FROM probe_table
      WHERE probe @> '{"myProbe":{"ip": "1.1.1.1"}}';
```

*ERROR:  operator does not exist: text @> unknown*

and this:

```
SELECT * FROM probe_table WHERE probe->myProbe->>ip = '1.1.1.1'
```

*ERROR:  column "myProbe" does not exist*

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Fixed the question, the error is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use single quotes for the parameters of the `->` or `->>` operators. And the message "*operator does not exist: text @> unknown*" indicates your column is of type `text` not `json` (or `jsonb` which it should be), so you need to cast it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM probe_table 
WHERE probe::jsonb -> 'myProbe' ->> 'ip' = '1.1.1.1'
```

Or

```
SELECT * 
FROM probe_table
WHERE probe::jsonb @> '{"myProbe":{"ip": "1.1.1.1"}}';
```